# Can we automatically catch some common formatting errors?

Tags: feature-request, mathjax

The one I've been seeing by far the most often occurs when users new to MathJax write something like `{$a,b,c$}` instead of `$\{a,b,c\}$`. Would it be possible to look for instances of `{$` and `$}` and gently suggest that "If you are trying to write braces (curly brackets) in mathematics mode, please use `\{` and `\}`"? It would also pay to check for the strings "sin", "cos", "tan", "dim", etc. that are not preceded by a backslash.